# Clicking children of class in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is sample html , where i am trying to click close button , there are many close buttons, but i want to click close button that is inside class *mytop*

```
<div class="mytop">
<a class="mychild" role="button" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to get javascript equivalent code for below jquery

```
$(".mytop").children(".mychild").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var topEl = document.querySelector('.mytop');
var closeBtn = topEl.querySelector('a.mychild');
closeBtn.click();
```

Comment: Read question , I need in pure javascript

Comment: Edited - see if it fits your bill

Answer (score 1):

grap class by `getElementsByClassName` and use `addEventListener` for event function..

> Use window.onload because you can only grap childnode after your document is loaded

```
window.onload = function(){
var top = document.getElementsByClassName("mytop");
  top[0].children[0].onclick = function(){
        alert(this.className); //mychild
  };  
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. Since @vishnu wants to add click listener to the child element

Comment: Thanks I see. @SESN

Answer (score 1):

**Use [`document.querySelector(<selector string>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**

For your use case, the code would look something like the following:

```
var closeButton = document.querySelector('.mytop a.mychild');
closeButton.click();
```

Am am assuming you wanted to simulate a click - not listen for one and fire a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var child = document.getElementsByClassName("mytop").childNodes;
 child[0].onclick = function(){
    alert("dsf");
 };
```

Right i am selecting the first child element only in the above code.

Comment: He's not adding an event listener, he's sending a click event.

Comment: At initial stage, the question is for click event. It has been edited after that

Comment: I don't see that in the edit history. The only edit was to add a missing quote.

Comment: Then Sry for my mistake. i will edit the code according to the needs